# Hide a specific <p/> tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a method that returns the p element, which I want to delete. Right now I am calling the get method(database fetch) after delete so that renderMessages is called again on render and update with new data. I want to simply hide it without calling any other method. I am not able to do this. How should I approach it?

```
renderMessages = (messages) => {
 return messages.map((message) => (
 <p>{message.content}
   <Tooltip title="Delete">
      <DeleteOutlined
         onClick={() => {
          this.delete(message.id);
         }}
   </Tooltip>
 </p>
 ));
 }
```

Comment: If `this.delete(message.id)` removes the message from `messages`, then it won't be there to be mapped.

Comment: If you have multiple `p` tags then just give them a `class` to the element and hide that element from selecting by their `class` using `CSS` only.

Comment: But the whole idea behind React is that you change the model and the view should react to that change; your code should not be altering the view directly... @ShubhamBaranwal.

Comment: @HereticMonkey true, but since messages is a state (which I got from fetching data), it still holds the deleted message. coz there is no update in the state - messages.

Comment: That's something that needs to be in your question at the start, not in a comment after the fact.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry for that, I found a solution so I am going to filter my messages with the message on delete. update the new state messages and call renderMessages again with the filtered data. No need to fetch data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an id to the `<p id=message.uniquefield>` element then call your hide function on that